# random prefix generating in cypress, its different each time the test runs

Tags: javascript, testing, cypress

I am trying to create a test that fills out a form, but one specific pages of the application there is a random prefix appearing in the ID of the textarea element.

#\35 f6b1d68-7e11-403d-bde0-90cb0a452d9e_e2aa87af-c799-4cf5-9289-46aedc7eb226_comment_textarea

then the second time I run the test I get

#\31 f6b1d68-7e11-403d-bde0-90cb0a452d9e_e2aa87af-c799-4cf5-9289-46aedc7eb226_comment_textarea

my first thought was to add the data-cy to the html, but that hasnt worked either, it just resorts back to using the ID with the random prefix (#\random number). any ideas on how to fix this? and if not, is there a way to get one textarea, fill it out, and then move to the next one (sort of like .next(), but that hasnt worked either)

Comment: Probably a good idea to show the code you have done for the test. Adding a data-cy attribute and then using it to locate the element should work.

Comment: New Front End frameworks are generating the Id attribute. So you can not use Id as a selector, it is used internally in the framework. You still can use HTML tag name and or class names any other attributes which can identify the DOM you need.
Can you copy the HTML code of the textarea you try to get?

Comment: <input autocapitalize="on" autocomplete="off" class="input-container__field" id="d9bf0ad8-1d1e-4aac-84d8-7b1d1e618b5b-name" maxlength="9999" name="name" type="text" value="test building 2751">

I understand both your replies, but im not sure I have explained the issue well. if I use the data-cy attribute, it wont show up in this specific case. the problem here is that when I run the test ONLY on this page, and a few others, the ID ends up being changed with a '\34' or a '\32' prefix, but the rest of the ID stays the same. its like cypress is fixated on this weird Id.

Comment: to further explain, if I add the data-cy to this element, and run the test, it will show up. the problem is that regardless of using the data-cy, or the ID, it will still place that '\34' or other random number in front. nothing else is changing except for this random prefix